# How do you AB test with Google Optimize on elements that have dynamic variables?

Tags: ab-testing, google-optimize

Im currently using Google Optimize's editor and I need to make an edit on an element that contains some dynamic variables. However when I edit the html, it renders the plain text and therefore it updates without the dynamic variable in place.

For example in the code it might be set up as `<p>{{ user.name }}</p>` but when I use the editor to edit the html it will show it as `<p>John Smith</p>` but if I apply changes it will replace my dynamic variable with the plain text.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try instead of editing the HTML via replace, you can insert/append/prepend.
[image]

Of course, this might mean you need to do some clever things with your code. Provide the before and after in your question and we can talk specifics.

Another thing you can try is to not use edit HTML and just use the editor to change the styling.